# Reference for probability exercises

Tags: probability, reference-request

I'm looking for challenging exercises in probability. The textbook I'm using now is Sheldon Ross's A First Course in Probability, which contains too many exercises. I don't think I have the energy to work through them all, and I don't know which ones are challenging enough.

Comment: Does it contain too many easy exercises, not simply too many exercises? If you seek out exercises while saying your course text has too many and you can't figure out the challenging ones, it comes across like you don't have the time to actually try the exercises already available to you (rather than that you find them too simple). Why not just work with the exercises at the end of the chapters instead of the beginning?

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking here to seek for alternative reference.

Answer (score 2):

*One Thousand Exercises in Probability* by Grimmett and Stirzaker